# How can I copy JSON files in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I have JSON files (es.json, en.json, ch.json) in "src\app\submodules\submodule1_src\assets\i18n".
I need that when doing "ionic build", these JSON files are copied to "src\assets\i18n\submodule1_src" automatically. In Ionic 3 this was done with @ionic/app-scripts, but it is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

Add in 'ionic.config.json':

```
"hooks": {
    "build:before": "./scripts/build-before.js"
},
```

And the content of 'build-before.js':

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function() {
   fs.copyFile(
      'src/app/submodules/submodule1/assets/i18n/es.json',
      'src/assets/i18n/submodule1/es.json',
      (err) => {});
}
```